# Facebook like style, Refresh ListView and Notify

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-listview

I have implemented a listview which consist of text and image from a json parse.
Wish to do something like the facebook app does.
Refresh automatically, sync json from the server and notify user like "2 New Stories" (see the image attached below), then attach the new stories to the top of existing list view.
I have no idea how "2 New Stories" notification emerges from the listview.
Kindly help me to implement this like facebook style listview.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Crouton library and modify it a little to achieve the style you want.

[Follow this link for more info & implementation details](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/useful-android-libraries-crouton/)

Comment: I read it already. I need internal notifications like facebook.

Comment: Is not something easy. You should start by implementing a Service that keeps constant connection with the Server

Comment: of course! I'm searching for persons who tried this or idea to implement this.